# PowerShell script isn't copying like I want

Tags: powershell, scripting, directory, subdirectory, copy-item

Right in the beginning I should note that I am a bloody beginner because I can't attend it classes in my grade.

I want to create a PowerShell script which will copy everything from

**C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\test(lots of folders)**

to

**C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\neu(lots of folders with the exact same names as above)\price**

As an absolute beginner I thought that it will be ok to replace the variable folder name with `$_Name` because it is the same name in both but I am obviously wrong and don't know why.
Here is my attempt

```
Copy-Item "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\test\$_name\*" -Destination "C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\neu\$_Name\price" -Recurse
```

It is copying something but in one package in a new folder in "neu".

I can't avoid creating this script because it would take me at least two or three days to do it by hand.
I am also sorry for my poor English skills

Thank you

Comment: I read your question twice and still don't understand what you are asking (sorry).

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 2):

the `$_` represents the current *pipeline* item. i don't see a pipeline in there ... [*grin*]

the following works by grabbing every file in the source dir & its subdirs, and copying that structure to the destination dir. it uses `Splatting` to structure the parameters neatly.

```
$SourceDir = "$env:TEMP\Apps - Copy"
$DestDir = "$env:TEMP\Apps - Copy - Two"

$CI_Params = @{
    LiteralPath = $SourceDir
    Destination = $DestDir
    Force = $True
    Recurse = $True
    }
Copy-Item @CI_Params
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct:

```
$src = 'C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\test'
$dst = 'C:\Users\Robert\Desktop\neu\{0}\price'

Get-ChildItem $src -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item -Path "$($_.FullName)\*" -Destination ($dst -f $_.BaseName) -Recurse -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Remove -WhatIf to actually do it.

Comment: I've tried it but it keeps shredding my other files already located in there. It's also stopping after some folders.